# Obfuscation - renaming variables with mono.cecil

Tags: c#, mono, obfuscation

I'm trying to write an obfuscator using mono.cecil and now working on renaming variables. I know that variable names are not stored in assembly (which I provide to the obfuscator) but in the pdb. Is there a way I can do the renaming using only the assembly (generating pdb and then renaming for example)?

Comment: Are you trying to obfuscate the PDB? What would be the point in obfuscating variables if they don't appear in the compiled code?

Comment: I'm trying to obfuscate executable so when I decompile it the variables will have random names. I can rename the class definition and the methods but variables don't change and I can't figure out the code to make it happen.

Comment: Eh? This whole question doesn't make much sense to me. Why would you distribute a pdb in your scenario? And if you don't distribute any pdb, there's no variable name anywhere, so there's variable name that needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

No need to go into pdb things here ...

```
using Mono.Cecil;

...


AssemblyDefinition asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("path to your program");

foreach (TypeDefinition t in asm.MainModule.Types)
{
  if (!t.Name == "<Module>")//global type
   {
     foreach (MethodDefinition m in t.Methods)
     {
       m.Name = "New Name for your method";
       // You better use a random name & an array where you can put
       // names that has been already used in order to avoid having twice 
       // the same name 
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Renaming methods and renaming variables are two different things. The question asks about renaming variables.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't distribute a pdb with the obfuscated assembly.

If you need to rename variables in your pdb:

- you need Cecil.Pdb.dll
- load the pdb after the assembly with `assembly.MainModule.LoadSymbols()`
- modify the name of a variable with `variableDefinition.Name = newName`
- save the pdb with `assembly.MainModule.SaveSymbols()`